# Proper method of populating a dropdown in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is how I've implemented my dropdown from my model. I just want to check if this is the proper way to do it or is there an easier method? It seems quite convoluted.

The model of my list:

```
public class ApplicationRolesDropdownListDetailViewModel
{
    public String RoleId { get; set; }
    public String ApplicationRoleName { get; set; }
}
```

The viewmodel that goes to my view

```
public class ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel
{
    public SelectList Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The controller that gets the list of items and puts it in a dropdown in a view:

```
    public ActionResult NewRole()
    {
        var applicationRoles = applicationRolesData.GetAllApplicationRoles();
        ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel ardlvm = new ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel();
        ardlvm.Roles = new SelectList(applicationRoles, "RoleId", "ApplicationRoleName");
        return View("~/Views/Users/Modals/AddRole.cshtml", ardlvm);
    }
```

My View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Roles,Model.Roles, new { @id = "role", @class = "dropdown" })
    </div>
```

Also, I can't seem to get the RoleId when I select an item from the list via javascript.

EDIT: Added my GetApplicationRoles

```
    public List<ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel > GetAllApplicationRoles()
    {
        List<ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel > data = new List<ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel >();
        try
        {
            var applicationRoles = dbContext.AspNetRolesExtendedDetails.ToList();
            data = (from ar in applicationRoles
                    join a in dbContext.AspNetApplications
                     on ar.ApplicationId equals a.Id
                    select new ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel 
                    {
                        RoleId = ar.Id,
                        ApplicationRoleName = ar.Name + " ( " + a.Name + " )"
                    }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e, AspNetEventLogs.NotFound);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: You cant get a roleid because your model is for the whole list, not a single item

Comment: What should I adjust? I'm quite confused with the last step.

Comment: I would recommend joining CodeReview.StackExchange and asking this question there, instead. Here it is likely to be closed as 'opinion-based'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**ViewModel**:

```
public class ApplicationRolesViewModel
{
    // Display Attribute will appear in the Html.LabelFor
    [Display(Name = "User Role")]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult NewRole()
    {
        var roleData = new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>();
        applicationRolesData.GetAllApplicationRoles().Foreach(x =>
                   roleData.Add( new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = x.RoleId.ToString(),
                            Text = x.ApplicationRoleName
                        });
       );
        ApplicationRolesViewModel ardlvm = new ApplicationRolesViewModel();
        ardlvm.Roles = new SelectList(roleData , "Value", "Text")
        return View("~/Views/Users/Modals/AddRole.cshtml", ardlvm);
    }
```

**View**:

```
@model ApplicationRolesViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, Model.Roles)
```

And  to get the currently selected value of dropdown in `Jquery`:

```
$('#RoleId').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
$('#RoleId:selected').text();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I added my GetApplicationRoles as well because I can't get .Select at all when trying your solution

Comment: @JianYA What is `GetAllApplicationRoles` response type?

Comment: ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel

Comment: @JianYA So you have one role with id in `ApplicationRolesDropdownListViewModel` ?

Comment: It should return a list of items

Comment: @JianYA Please share `GetAllApplicationRoles` code

Comment: I added it in my questions

Comment: @JianYA Add using `System.Linq;`

Comment: Yeah I tried but its not appearing.

Comment: @JianYA can you get `.Foreach` instead `.Select` ?

Comment: Yeah I can. Should I break it into multiple lines instead?

Comment: @JianYA I update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, one more question, how do I get this value via jquery?

Comment: @JianYA Answer updated.

Comment: Using `new SelectList(...)` to create a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in pointless extra overhead.